# Boxplot in r - how to plot having two columns (one with values referring to different categories)

Tags: r, boxplot

I want to plot a boxplot. I have 10 questions, and 200 people answered on those 10 questions. I coded two columns based on these data. One column consists of values (from 1 to 7 - answer that each participant gave on a given question), and the second one consists of names of each question (200 times there is First, 200 times Second, 200 times Third and so on). It looks like this:

```
Question Value
First    3
Second   7
Third    4
Fourth   3
...
Tenth    1
First    5
Second   6
```

And I've been trying to plot a boxplot, using ggplot, but the main problem is that I want to have names of questions on y axis, and the means and SD on x axis, but the means should be referring only to the given question (i.e., I want to show on a plot what was the mean of all partcipants answering on the First, Second etc. question). I've tried to use some functions like:

```
ggplot(data=data, aes(x=data$Value(by='data$Question'), y=data$Question)) + geom_boxplot()
```

or

```
ggplot(data=data, aes(x=data$Value~data$Question, y=data$Question)) + geom_boxplot()
```

but all the time the means are being computed for the whole data$Value column, without distinguishing which values are referring to which question. How can I tell R to plot a boxplot like this:

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Standard box plot:

```
ggplot(data, aes(Question, Value)) + 
    geom_boxplot() +
    coord_flip()
```

Mean-SD-Boxplot:

```
data%>% 
      group_by(Question) %>% 
      summarise(mean = mean(Value), sd = sd(Value)) %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x = Question, y = Value)) + 
      geom_crossbar(aes(ymin = mean - sd, ymax = mean + sd), size = .5, width = 0.5) + 
      geom_linerange(aes(ymin = mean - 2 * sd, ymax = mean - sd), size = .5) +
      geom_linerange(aes(ymin = mean + sd, ymax = mean + 2 * sd), size = .5) +
      coord_flip()
```

Using `mtcars` as example data:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(mpg), sd = sd(mpg)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(cyl), y = mean)) + 
  geom_crossbar(aes(ymin = mean - sd, ymax = mean + sd), size = .5, width = 0.5) + 
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin = mean - 2 * sd, ymax = mean - sd), size = .5) +
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin = mean + sd, ymax = mean + 2 * sd), size = .5) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Oh my god, I've been struggling to get such result for the past three hours... Stefan, you are a genius :)) Maybe you could shed some light also on how to replace median and quartiles, and use means and standard deviations as the boxplot??

Comment: Okay. I see. I think in this case we have to use geom_crossbar. I check it out.

Comment: Okay. Have a look. 1. Use summarise to compute the mean and sd. 2. Use geom_crossbar and two times geom_linerange to construct the Mean-SD-Boxplot. I have the lines so that the span from mean - 2*sd to mean + 2*sd. To me, this makes more sense for this kind if plot than the interquartile range.